# How to get partial view to asynchronously get data from controller. Perceived Performance application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, partial-views

**Update:**

I have a page that loads an html view as follows:

```
<div class="center-box">
    <div id="ourTeam">
        <div class="arrowLeft"></div>
        <div class="arrowRight"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="containerParent">
        @Html.Partial("Team", Model.TeamMembers == null ? new List<UsersViewModel>() : Model.TeamMembers)
    </div>
</div>
```

The model passed into this view is `PagesViewModel` which includes a bunch of display variables and a few objects. It also includes this:

```
public IEnumerable<UsersViewModel> TeamMembers { get; set; }
```

Which is what is sent into the Partial View. The controller for the partial view looks as follows:

```
public ActionResult Team()
{
    getInfo getting = new getInfo();
    IEnumerable<UsersViewModel> getUsers = getting.getDisplayUsers();
    return PartialView("Team", getUsers);
}
```

But when I run it the code never gets here. It just displays the empty List I sent into from the View.

The name of the partial view file is: `Team.cshtml`

**The goal is to get the data from the controller for the partial view**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when Partial View Model passed from the View is `null`, you can handle it like this:

```
<div class="containerParent">
        @Html.Partial("Team", Model.TeamMembers ==null ? new List<UsersViewModel>() : Model.TeamMembers)
    </div>
```

or make sure that at least passed Collection is at least instantiated via constructor of ViewModel

if you are trying to render partial view via controller, then you have to use [`@Html.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Html.Action("actionname","controllername")
```

Comment: Will that make the partial view hit the controller?

Comment: No it will not go to controller

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question. I was doing this before but the problem is that I need to get this partial view to hit that controller asynchronously.